# What is equivalent of using Python's Asyncio for generating HTTP requests in Scala?

Tags: python, scala

I am currently trying to build an asynchronous client-side data-fetcher (via HTTP) using **Scala**. The fetched data will be parsed, and inserted into a database, but that is beyond the scope of this question.

The main objectives are:

1. Build a function to extract data from an api asynchronously.
2. Have control over request frequency (in other words: have the flexibility to handle rate limits).

To offer better insight to what I am trying to do, I have written some code in Python to help expressing my question better.

I first define a function that creates async http requests (I used [aiohttp](https://docs.aiohttp.org/en/stable/) as I found it expressive for my intent):

```
from aiohttp import ClientResponse, ClientSession, ClientError, http_exceptions 


async def fetch_data(url: str, method: str, session: ClientSession, **kwargs) -> dict:
    """
    Request wrapper that fetches data. Passes kwargs to session.
    Args:
        :param url: api endpoint used (eg. https://foo.bar.com/api/v3/baz)
        :param method: HTTP method used (eg. GET, POST...etc.)
        :param session: aiohttp.ClientSession object. The main entry point for all client API operations.
    Kwargs:
        ___ : Includes other KWARGS that may be passed to a session (eg. Headers, SSL...etc.)
    Returns:
        Dict
     """
    response: ClientResponse = await session.request(url=url, method=method, **kwargs)
    response.raise_for_status()  # Raises an aiohttp.ClientResponseError if the response status is 400 or higher
    logger.info("Got response [%s] for request: %s", response.status, url)
    data: dict = await response.json()
    return data
```

I would later use this function to retrieve the data and do actual work with it (note the [limit](https://docs.aiohttp.org/en/stable/client_reference.html?highlight=limit#aiohttp.BaseConnector.limit) on the TCPConnector, which limits the total number for simultaneous connections):

```
H = {"Authorization": "orgId={org_id}".format(org_id=config.account_id())}
C = config.cert_dir()

async def main():
    sslcontext = ssl.create_default_context(cafile=None)
    sslcontext.load_cert_chain(certfile=C + "Admin_API_access.pem", keyfile=C + "Admin_API_access.key")
    connector = aiohttp.TCPConnector(limit=0, ssl=sslcontext)  # limit=0 can be used to reduce the number of async requests

    async with aiohttp.ClientSession(connector=connector) as context:
        # Call API and do something with the data (eg. write to a file)
```

To my understanding (and also to my confusion), there are several ways of getting this done in Scala. What is the equivalent of the aforementioned Python code in Scala to generate HTTP requests without blocking. As Asyncio is single-threaded, I am not particularly looking for a single-threaded solution, but rather an asynchronous one.

And lastly, I am **not** looking for someone to write the code for me, I am rather seeking conceptual understanding of potential solutions that I can go for, which offer the same functionality.

Comment: I haven't used it myself, but [Dispatch](https://github.com/dispatch/reboot) is a very common async http library for Scala that might be worth looking into.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fundamentally in Scala, asynchrony is represented by `Future`, which one can think of as a wrapper of a single object that:

- may at some point in time (possibly in the past) be completed
- if it's completed, it is either completed with an object or an exception

One can register callbacks which will operate on the `Future` at some point after it completes; one can also treat the `Future` in a manner very similar to a collection with `map`, `flatMap`, etc. to transform it (behind the scenes, these operations register a callback and return a new `Future` which is completed by the callback: using `map`, `flatMap`, `recover` and friends is generally preferable to manual callback registration).

This is a very general API and there are many, many ways to implement it.  In general, if a Scala library returns `Future`s, it supports asynchronous operation out of the box.  There's no shortage of libraries which will yield a `Future` of an HTTP request, including but most definitely not limited to:

- Akka HTTP
- Dispatch
- Gigahorse
- Play WS

Choosing such a library is basically a matter of taste: other libraries in use may guide you toward a particular library (e.g. if you're using other Akka libraries, it might make sense to use Akka HTTP), and you may find one library or another better supports a particular use-case.

Also, if a particular library doesn't give you a `Future`, you can pretty easily wrap it:

```
import some.blocking.http.request.library

import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext

def asyncRequestUrl(url: String)(implicit ectx: ExecutionContext): Future[Response] =
  Future {
    library.request(url)
  }
```

`scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext` represents a threadpool with a backlog of tasks to execute in the pool.  `Future { code... }` (technically `Future.apply`) adds a task to execute `code...` and complete a future (which is immediately returned) with the result of execution.  Note that, because a threadpool nearly always has an upper limit on the number of threads in it, the task will stay in the "scheduled but not executing" state for as long as all threads in the pool are busy with other tasks.

If the caller does not provide an `ExecutionContext`, the compiler will flag this as an error and may suggest using `scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global`.  Using this `ExecutionContext` is probably OK in dev/test environments, but one will almost certainly want to create a custom `ExecutionContext` with more threads than the default global context, at least for making HTTP requests.  Using an async-by-design library like the ones I listed above will likely "just work" in terms of choosing a suitable threadpool (and probably be configurable if one finds it doesn't "just work").

If one is in an FP-oriented codebase, one will probably want to use something like [http4s](https://http4s.org/v0.18/client/), which uses a slightly different model than "vanilla" Scala for asynchrony (e.g. `ConcurrentEffect` from Cats Effect).  There are ways to make it work with vanilla Scala, if one is so inclined.